# Dataset Designer functionality in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am developing an Asp.Net WebForms website. I am used from my prior project to the "dataset designer", it was my main worksite, I had there all my tables and also hundreds of queries which I could easily call from code like this: "this.InventoryTableAdapter.MyQuery('parameters'), it was great, but I can't find such a thing in Asp.Net, am I missing something. how do you access your special queries in code. do you have to write cumbersome ADO.Net code for each small thing, can someone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still add a database designer to your .NET application.  Today's standard ORM for .NET is Entity Framework, although many other good options exist.  One thing to research is Entity Framework Database First.  Here's how to get started...

1. In your project, choose to Add New Item.  In the Add New Item dialog choose the Data items and then select ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Click Add.
2. In the Entity Data Model Wizard, select EF Designer from database.
3. If you have database connections defined within your development environment, you may see one of these connections pre-selected. Or, you can create a new connection to your database.
4. After setting up your connection, select the tables you want to generate models for.  These will be the tables available in your database designer.

This is a very high level how to.  You can read more about this approach here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

Another ORM option is LinqToSql.  You can read more about creating a database designer ".dbml" file using LinqToSql here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try it, just to be clear, it means there is no dataset designer in asp.net like it is in winfiorms programs?

Comment: Whether you're talking about WebForms, WinForms, MVC, or even a console application they all have access to the same data objects.  If you're using LinqToSql or Entity Framework, you can create database diagrams using the method above.  Then you can see your tables, sprocs, views, etc... and easily integrate them into your application.  That being said, it does seem like this approach has fallen out of favor and something called Code First is more widely adopted.